# how can i use hibernate instead eclipselink in weblogic?

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I have an application wheeling in jboss server, and actually is using hibernate-jpa-2.0, when i tryied to run this app on the weblogic i see an error from the eclipselink about JPA annotations. I think am have two options in this case, change my application to eclipselink OR use hibernate in weblogic. The question is, how can i declare in my weblogic-application.xml / weblogic.xml to use hibernate and not the eclipselink. This is possible ? The error that is happening is as follows:

> Substituted for missing class Exception [EclipseLink-7298] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd) -
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: The mapping [associado] from the embedded ID class [class
>   br.com.project.web.model.associate.pk.AssociateMaintainPK] is
>   an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used
>   with an embedded ID specification (attribute [.AssociateMaintainPK]
>   from the source [class
>   br.com.project.web.model.associate.AssociateMaintain]) can
>   only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or
>   change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.

Comment: you could set the provider in persistence.xml (in provider tag) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1417

Comment: in my persistence.xml is setted to use de hibernet, but apparently is using the eclipselink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reference your hibernate libraries from your weblogic deployment descriptor (either weblogic.xml if your bundle is a `war` or weblogic-application.xml for an `ear`). Either deploy the libraries colocated with your app or as a set of shared libraries if used by multiple apps deployed on the same weblogic instance (this is the solution I use). This way WLS will use the library referenced instead of the default implementation bundled with weblogic (EclipseLink for JPA api).

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd 
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
... config stuff
<!-- hibernate orm -->
<library-ref>
    <library-name>hibernate-core</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>hibernate-entitymanager</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>hibernate-envers</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</library-name>
</library-ref>
<!-- hibernate orm deps -->
<library-ref>
    <library-name>dom4j</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>hibernate-commons-annotations</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>jboss-logging</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>jboss-logging-annotations</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>jandex</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>javassist</library-name>
</library-ref>
```